# Show tags in header InfluxDB query

Tags: jquery, influxdb

I have the following query on InfluxDB.

```
SELECT MEAN(value) FROM cpu_value WHERE time >="2015-11-10T15:08:30.608Z" GROUP BY type,type_instance
```

The query gives an output with time and mean as headers. Is it possible to show type and type_instance in the header too?

```
time | mean
```

I'd like to have such an output:

```
time | mean | type | type_instance
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to run:

```
SELECT MEAN(value), type, type_instance FROM cpu_value WHERE time >="2015-11-10T15:08:30.608Z" GROUP BY type,type_instance
```

Note the `, type, type_instance` in the select clause as well. Given you are grouping by `type, type_instance` .. you can just add them in select as well.